# C# Method to Return 1 of 3 Possible Enums

Tags: c#, methods, return-value

I have the three following enums:

```
public enum SensorTypeA{A1,A2,...,A12};
public enum SensorTypeB{B1,B2,...,B12};
public enum SensorTypeC{C1,C2,...,C12};
```

I am communicating with a sensor circuit via serial port and want to see which sensor is being used at location "x" so I created a method

```
public ???? GetSensorTypeAtLocation(int x)
{
   ...
   // Send serial command and receive response.
   string responseCommand = SendReceive(String.Format("SR,ML,{0},\r", x));

   // Process response command string and return result.
   return ???? (could be any of the 3 possible enums)
}
```

Is there a way I can return any of the possible enums? Cast to `object`? Better way?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

There are multiple sensors for each sensor type. I changed the enums to reflect this.

Comment: And what if enum value overlap?

Comment: Why are there three enums? Are they different types of sensor?

Comment: I don't know if you can do that with enums, I would create 3 classes all derived from same base class and have ClassA, ClassB and ClassC with a public enum SensorType inside.

Comment: public enum SensorType { A, B, C }

Comment: Yes, they are different types of sensors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for Enum.TryParse().

```
public Enum GetSensorTypeAtLocation(int x)
{
   ...
   // Send serial command and receive response.
   string responseCommand = SendReceive(String.Format("SR,ML,{0},\r", x));

   //Try to parse the response into a value from one of the enums;
   //the first one that succeeds is our sensor type.
   SensorTypeA typeAresult;
   if(Enum.TryParse(responseCommand, typeAResult)) return typeAresult;
   SensorTypeB typeBresult;
   if(Enum.TryParse(responseCommand, typeBResult)) return typeBresult;
   SensorTypeC typeCresult;
   if(Enum.TryParse(responseCommand, typeCResult)) return typeCresult;
}
```

The problem will be that you cannot create overloads based on return type, and therefore you will not know exactly what the system will return (but the CLR will know at runtime, and you can interrogate the type of the return value to get a specific answer).

I would seriously consider an Enum `SensorType` containing A, B and C values. Then, the function can return a definite answer based on what type of response the sensor gave:

```
public SensorType GetSensorTypeAtLocation(int x)
{
   ...
   // Send serial command and receive response.
   string responseCommand = SendReceive(String.Format("SR,ML,{0},\r", x));

   // Process response command string and return result.
   SensorTypeA typeAresult;
   if(Enum.TryParse(responseCommand, typeAResult)) return SensorType.A;
   SensorTypeB typeBresult;
   if(Enum.TryParse(responseCommand, typeBResult)) return SensorType.B;
   SensorTypeC typeCresult;
   if(Enum.TryParse(responseCommand, typeCResult)) return SensorType.C;
}
```

Now, you know from the return value itself, plain as day, the type of the sensor.

Comment: I think I will be going with your first suggestion. I simplified the post a bit, of the enumerations two are sensor types and one is a "calculation type". This calculation type is ADD, SUB, ... where ADD could be equal to SensorTypeA.A12+SensorTypeB.2 or some other combination. Because of this, I will have to interrogate at runtime but that shouldn't be too painful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the `Enum` part of the question completely because the root of the question is "Can a function return multiple types". The answer to this is "yes" but you'll have to return a higher level class, in this case `Object` and you'll need to do type checking after returning:

```
    public enum SensorTypeA { A = 0 };
    public enum SensorTypeB { B = 1 };
    public enum SensorTypeC { C = 2 };

    private object GetSensorTypeAtLocation()
    {
        return SensorTypeB.B;
    }

    private void YourMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object value = GetSensorTypeAtLocation();
        if (value is SensorTypeA)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
        else if (value is SensorTypeB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
        else if (value is SensorTypeC)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown");
        }
    }
```